# Maximum line length Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line

Tags: ada

I'm using GNATColl-sql to create SQL queries.
I was thinking to perform a visual inspection of the generated SQL code using the "To_String" method, but when I call *Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line* or *Ada.Text_IO.Put* to see the SQL string, a carriage return is being added to the output.

For example, I cannot share the real query, if I expect:

```
SELECT orders.order_id, customers.last_name FROM orders INNER JOIN customers ON orders.customer_id = customers.customer_id WHERE orders.order_id <> 1 ORDER BY orders.order_id;
```

What I'm getting after Put_Line/Put instead (notice the line break at *customers.cust* **CRLF** *omer_id*):

```
SELECT orders.order_id, customers.last_name FROM orders INNER JOIN customers ON orders.customer_id = customers.cust
omer_id WHERE orders.order_id <> 1 ORDER BY orders.order_id;
```

I first suspected that carriage return was due to a GNATColl-sql bug, but now I suspect the procedure Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line has a maximum line length to print. Am I right?

I tried the procedure "Ada.Text_IO.Set_Line_Length" with a huge count value, greater than the position where the carriage return is added, but it is printed at the same place.

How can I print a large string on a line instead of several lines?

**New suspicion:**

I was running my main on GNATStudio, but if I directly run the main.exe on a cmd I can see the SQL on a line now. GNATStudio may be configuring a maximum line length for printing.

Comment: Adding a Newline is what Put_Line does. Hence its name. If you don't want a Newline, use Put.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Have you tried calling Set_Line_Length(0)? As the manual says, "The value zero for To specifies an unbounded line length."

Comment: @OndrejTucny I've  added an example to clarify; I cannot share the query sorry, but in my case Put_Line/Put is breaking the line at column 427 I guess, because I'm not sure if it is caused by GNATColl-sql or Ada.Text_IO, I suspect it is the latter.

Comment: @k314159 thanks! I tried as the first statement before put_line but it prints the same

Comment: @user_1818839 that's not what I mean. I've added an example to clarify it. My problem is that both Put_Line and Put are breaking the string to be represented into two lines, one up to column 427, and second line from there up to the end of the string. I want everything to be printed into one line, without linebreaks

Comment: I don't think Ada.Text_IO has any standardized limit on the emitted line length, and it would be strange if an implementation has it. My Ada environment (GNAT on Mac OS-X) has no problem with an Ada program that concatenates all lines of a 3185-octet, 168-line input file into a single-line file of 3018 bytes. How do you know that there is a line break after 427 characters? Have you saved the output file and scanned it for LF or CR characters, or just looked at it on the screen?

Comment: If your string (let's say it's called `MyQuery`) is broken into two lines after 427 characters, then try calling `Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(MyQuery(100..MyQuery'Length))`. If it now breaks the line after 327 characters, then you know that the line break is part of the string itself.

Comment: @k314159 better than my solution printing the string as I expect it manually, which, curiously, adds a linebreak at a different position (I suppose is due to special characters). Thank you a lot, thus I have ensured that the linebreak is due to Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line and that I built the query correctly.

Comment: @Albatros23: Using `Ada.Strings.Fixed`, try `Put_Line (50 * "0123456789")`.

Comment: @trashgod thank you for your answer. I figured out that GNATStudio could have a maximum line length set up on its console, thus I tryed to run my main on a windows cmd and there I can see the query into one line correctly.

Comment: @NiklasHolsti so sorry for not answering you, I didn't see your message. I knew it because I copied the output from the GNATStudio console on Notepad++, to see the CR LF characters, but I could see the line change on the GNATStudio console. I figured out then that the linebreak could be due to the GNATStudio console configuration and I confirmed my suspicion running the executable on a windows cmd. On a windows cmd, I was able to see the whole query on a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line length in Ada is *unbounded* until explicitly changed, as by [`Set_Line_Length`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-10-4.html), or called for, as by [`New_Line`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-10-5.html). It may be that your command line console is wrapping the lines for readability. One way to test this is using [`Ada.Strings.Fixed`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-4-3.html#p105) to print a long line to the console:

```
Put_Line (50 * "0123456789");
```

You can also pipe the output to a utility that can format the output for closer inspection:

```
./main | hexdump -C
```

Your exact approach will depend on the console used. As you are using GNAT Studio, I see that it supports [*Defining the default command line*](https://docs.adacore.com/gps-docs/users_guide/_build/html/extending.html#defining-the-default-command-line).